# How to think of the location concept of a point?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, intuition, infinitesimals

It is said that *points are to be thought of as 0-dimensional*. It is also said that they *represent a position, i.e., a location.*

In the physical world, location obviously encompasses some area, say, the city of New York. It obviously has some boundaries within which it exists.

Now, in the abstract world, **how am I supposed to think of the location concept of a point.**

Comment: Consider the cartesian plane. Consider a circle centered in origin with radius whatever. Consider the intersection with $x$-axis. That is a *point*. Every "position" on the line is a point.

Comment: The problem is that when we use words like "position" and "location" in the physical world, they have different degrees of precision. I can say position as in "in the Milky Way" or "at this address....", or different extensions like "in NY" (which is a surface, more or less) or "in this portion of space". You should think of a point as a "precise" location, like "At this times I'll be at this address, in front of the gate". Anyway, when you picture an abstract object with physical concepts, there will always be a gap between the two

Comment: I think one problem in your understanding is the use of the word "obviously" in "location obviously encompasses some area" - which I do not think is so obvious (nor the general consent).